# System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:1, column:3]

Tags: apex, callout, rest, trailhead

I´m trying to complete a trailhead challenge but when I test the method, it appears the error

System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:1, column:3]

This is the json

```
{"animal":{"id":0,"name":"","eats":"","says":""}}
```

Also, when I run the same code on Execute Anonymous, it does work! So I don't know what else to do.

```
public class AnimalLocator {

public static String getAnimalNameById(integer id){
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals/' + id);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    Map<String,Object> result = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
    Map<String,Object> animal = (Map<String,Object>) result.get('animal');
    return (String)animal.get('name');
}
```

}

```
@isTest
public class AnimalLocatorTest {

@isTest static void testAnimalLocator(){
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new AnimalLocatorMock());

    String name = AnimalLocator.getAnimalNameById(0);

    System.assertEquals(name, 'Alex');
}
```

}

The error seems to be here `Map<String,Object> animal = (Map<String,Object>) result.get('animal');`

UPDATE 
The error was in the CalloutMock class, I was trying to create a JSON without the double quotes.

```
public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request){
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
    response.setBody('{"animal": {"id": 0, "name": "Alex", "eats": "", "says": ""}}');
    response.setStatusCode(200);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't valid JSON:

```
{
  animal: {
    id: 0,
    name: "",
    eats: "",
    says: "",
  }
}
```

and the error actually says exactly what's wrong:

> Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:1, column:3]

JSON keys are required to be quoted strings. You must quote "animal", "id", "name", "eats", and "says".

Comment: how can I do that in Apex? I'm aware that double quotes are not permitted.

Comment: You can use double quotes inside a single-quoted Apex string literal, if that's how you're constructing this. You might also check out static resource mocks, which are a neat way to store and produce JSON for use in HTTPCalloutMocks.

Answer (score 0):

I receive errors with the following JSON (provided by https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_add_products.htm)

> {"context":"{"quote":{"record":{"attributes":{"type":"SBQQ__Quote__c","url":"/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/SBQQ__Quote__c/a0p61000004IpR8AAK"},
> "Name":"Q-00905","Id":"a0p61000004IpR8AAK"},"nextKey":2,"netTotal":0.00,"lineItems":[],"lineItemGroups":[],
> "customerTotal":0.00},"products":[],"groupKey":0,
> "ignoreCalculate": true}"}

Initially it gave an error regarding context "Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: context at [line:1, column:13]"
However after adding escapes to the context it brings up errors similar to this pre-existing issue here on stackoverflow

": Unexpected character ('' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:1, column:3]"

As quotes are provided in the JSON, should this work or are there additional changes required?

Thanks for any help on this.